# what is the best way to implement communication with redis in python

Tags: python, class, redis

I am trying to write a module that communicates with redis. So far its doing following things.

1. Get the token
2. if token A then connect to redis A
3. else connect to redis B
4. get data for a specific key
5. delete a key

Here is what I have written:

```
import redis

def get_data(token):

    if token == "tokenA" 
        connection = redis.Redis(connection_pool=name_of_redis_engine1)
    else:   
        connection = redis.Redis(connection_pool=name_of_redis_engine2)

    data = connection.hgetall(token)
    if not data:
        raise Some Error

    return data

def delete_data(token):

    connection = redis.Redis(connection_pool=name_of_redis_engine)

    data = redis_connection.delete(token)
    if not data:
        raise Some Error

    return data
```

Since, there is a some duplicate data in both functions which is not a good approach. I was wondering about whats the best way to make it neat Maybe class? . Will appreciate any help alot.

Comment: What does `import redis` mean in your code?

Comment: @colonelpanic Its for Importing the redis-py module for python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankyou @yarkee. I have come up with the following solution. Will appreciate if anyone can point out some more better way.

```
class RedisClass(object):
def __init__(self, token=None):

    self.token = token

    if self.token == "TokenA":
        self.redis_connection = redis.Redis(connection_pool="RedisEngineA")
    else:
        self.redis_connection = redis.Redis(connection_pool="RedisEngineB")

def get_data(self):
    data = self.redis_connection.hgetall(self.token)
    if not data:
        raise AuthenticationError({"status: Invalid token"}, code=200, log_error=False)
    return data

def delete_data(self):
    data = self.redis_connection.delete(self.token)
    if not data:
        raise AuthenticationError({"status: Invalid token"}, code=200, log_error=False)
    return data
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it a class. Given your exact requirements, what you can do is:

```
class RedisStore:
    def __init__(self, default_connection, tokenA_connection):
        self._default_connection = default_connection
        self._tokenA_connection = tokenA_connection 

    def _chose_connection(token):
        if token == "tokenA" 
            return self._tokenA_connection
        else:   
            return self._default_connection

    def get_data(self, token):
        connection = self._chose_connection(token)
        data = connection.hgetall(token)
        if not data:
            raise Exception("Some Error")  # you can only raise exceptions, and you should use a more specific one

        return data

    def delete_data(self, token):
        connection = self._chose_connection(token)
        data = connection.delete(token)
        if not data:
            raise Exception("Some Error")  # if that is supposed to raise the same exception, you could generalize further...
        return data

redis_store = new RedisStore(redis.Redis(connection_pool=name_of_redis_engine1), redis.Redis(connection_pool=name_of_redis_engine2))
```

You can instantiate the class once and reuse it for multiple lookups/deletes.

Comment: I want  to have the logic of creating connection in the class. In your solution it seems that redis connections are already defined and are passed to the Class. Isnt it better that we create the connection here. that way we will have only that connection created that is needed. (from the token)

Comment: That depends on how unlikely it is that you will ever need the connection. If you store a reference to the RedisStore object and reuse it for multiple requests, only two connections are ever created. Also, creating things in constructors results in higher coupling between objects, so testing is harder. This way, you can inject mocked connections when testing.

Answer (score 0):

Make it be a class.

```
import redis

class RedisOp(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = redis.Redis(connection_pool=name_of_redis_engine)

    def get_data(self, token):
        data = self.connection.hgetall(token)
        if not data:
            raise Some Error
        return data

    def delete_data(self, token):
        data = self.connection.delete(token)
        if not data:
            raise Some Error
        return data


op = RedisOp()
print op.get_data('mykey')
op.delete_data('mykey')
```

Comment: I just realised that there was one more requirement. In my case there are two redis engines. And I am creating the connection based on the type of token that I get. and then the get_data and delete_data operation is the same regardless of the engine. I was wondering how can I do that.